# Presenting Built-In Self-Test Coverage

Tags: standard, documentation, self-test

I have a piece of code that performs self-test on various components of the board, like MCU, BLE, IMU, OLED, flash memory,  and etc.

What I'm trying to make is a document that would represent what these tests cover, or when you run the IMU test and it says "PASS", what does that actually mean. Or going from another direction, if I want to test BLE/OLED/MCU, what set of tests I need to run to have confidence that it's all working as expected.

Now, I know how to represent this data in a text format or in some table but even when I try my best this information gets too convoluted, confusing and looks like someone just threw up a bunch of data and you need to make sense of it.

What I'm looking for is something like industry standard way of representing this information, or best practice that would allow someone to take a look at a document and say: "Yes, this BLE test ensures that my chip is soldered properly, crystal is present and oscillating, firmware is running fine but it doesn't test the actual BLE antenna and tuning/matching component". Or from bottom up, someone says "I wan't to test that IMU is working properly, so I need to run these set of tests and they will ensure that chip is soldered properly, GPIOs are working, and device is registering 1G along X/Y/Z axis"

Any suggestions, examples or pointers on what to look for would be very appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need a manual that describes what each test does...perhaps look at some software manuals and see how they structure and organize their information?

Comment: There is no need for a manual, at least not in that format.
This would be more like helpful matrix that would be used in two situations:

Situation #1) I want to validate that component(s) are working, so I consult the document to see what set of tests I need to run and what they "guarantee"

Situation #2) Someone told me they are running this set of tests and they are passing, I want to see what they are covering and what they are not covering.
Matrix looks like a best platform to visualize this information but I'm not sure if there is a better way or how to avoid common mistakes?

Comment: I recall a sophisticated mobo design my colleague did with loop back on every IO , bus and analog IO. He wrote the machine code and it worked 1st time. Another used graphical object oriented module design with parameters to include self test for a video projector TV in our production.

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm trying to make is a document that would represent what these
>   tests cover

Then you have to think of your audience - who is the target audience? Could it be that one target audience requires different things than another i.e. if you are trying to sell this thing then, there might be this guy in a marketing department somewhere who thinks "we need one of these inside our product" so what would the document that meets his needs? If you are not trying to sell this wonderful thing then fine but you still need to think who your target audience is.

If you are just trying to impart detail to a softy you might format it totally different. You might need three or four entry point documents.

> Now, I know how to represent this data in a text format or in some
>   table but even when I try my best this information gets too
>   convoluted, confusing and looks like someone just threw up a bunch of
>   data and you need to make sense of it

Start at the basic picture i.e. like a break down of a part number: -

[image]

Everyone with a bit of [nous](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nous) should understand the above and you can nest deeper functionality explanations on seperate pages.

If there are different modes of functionality like in this: -

[image]

And they produce a different breakdown of the part structure (above) then start with the state machine then go to the part breakdowns for each state.

*NB the part breakdown is pretty much like what status registers represent*: -

[image]

If this answer has hit the spot then, you need to pay me some consultancy money LOL. If this answer is way off the mark then that means that you need to learn to improve your question making skills LOL\$^2\$.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for suggesting all these great ways to represent information. For now I'm going with matrix that shows elements in Y "axis" and then listing what is covered in X "axis". This matrix will have ~30 elements in Y and maybe 10-15 in X axis so this format seems like most consumable for now. Of course when this becomes larger, then matrix might no longer be the best way to represent the data.